# How do I put a shortcut on the Programs menu on Windows Mobile in the installer cab?

Tags: windows, vb.net, windows-mobile, cab

Where do I put the shortcut icon for my mobile application in the Installer project for a Windows Mobile project so that when the cab is installed the icon will show on the Programs Menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the file system editor you can right click -> "Add Special Folder" -> "Start Menu Folder". Then you right click in the folder and select "Create new Shortcut" and select your application.